# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable - while loading a Pytorch model

Tags: pytorch, yolov5

I have a model saved in the same directory as my ipynb file and it also loads when I do torch.load().

But, when I try to pass images or a video as input it gives me this error :
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Here's the SS :

[SS of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaVmt.png)

Let know if there's anything else I need to attach.

Comment: Please add the code instead of the picture.

Comment: You need to use model.load_state_dict(torch.load(Path')) in order to solve your problem.